# cannot recognize SIM card

Tags: sim-card

I am using Samsung Galaxy Premier(I9268) running CM 12.1. Several days ago, after some reboot, the phone **Suddenly** not recognize the SIM card. I have tried to use older updates, they all don't work. I have also tried to use the SIM on another phone, it is alright, proving that the SIM is OK to use. Can anyone tell me what problem I am having or help me solve that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried carefully cleaning the SIM and socket and reseating it?

Comment: yes, of course. Though I am done now by flashing to stock image in 4.1.2, I am still curious about that recognizing problem.

Comment: It works in stock 4.1.2, but not working in cm12/12.1